# vite is not auto reloading index.html on save after tailwind installation as postcss plugin

Tags: javascript, tailwind-css, vite, postcss, reloading

I have installed Vite with Tailwind. But after installing Tailwind , when I change the index.html file, the Vite server does not auto reload. It reloads when I save the file main.js.

### tailwind.config.js

```
module.exports = {
  content: ['./*.html', './src/**/*.{vue,js,ts,jsx,tsx}'],
  theme: {
    extend: {},
  },
  plugins: [],
};
```

### postcss.config.js

```
module.exports = {
  plugins: {
    tailwindcss: {},
    autoprefixer: {},
  },
}
```

### main.js

```
import './style.css';
```

### index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <link rel="icon" type="image/svg+xml" href="favicon.svg" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <title>Vite App</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="app"></div>
    <h1 class="text-blue-500">helo</h1>
    <script type="module" src="/main.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

### style.css

```
@tailwind base;
@tailwind components;
@tailwind utilities;
```

Answer (score 0):

If it's the `<h1 class="text-blue-500">helo</h1>` you expect to see, I had the same problem. Make sure you include the stylesheet in `index.html`:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="./src/index.css">
```

Tailwind is building properly when `main.js` gets built and updated with `Vite` and the stylesheet gets injected, but that's not happening for `index.html` when it has no reference to the stylesheet.